# PHP and MySQL change logged in user password form not updating password

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, authentication, warnings

I'm trying to allow the user to update their password once logged in, in a profile editing page. I have two problems. The first is that I get a warning which says

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects at most 1 parameter, 2 on line 115

which is

```
$stmt->execute(":password",$changed_password);
```

I have tried different syntax but get errors here.

The second problem is that the password is not actually updated. Here is the code (including how I create the connection to the db for the current user)

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once 'class.user.php';
  $user_home = new USER();
  $msg = '';

  if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
  {
     $user_home->redirect('signin.php');
  }

  $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=:uid");
  $stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  // print_r($row['learner_type']);
  ?>
```

The above code is at the start of my file.
The following code is triggered after the form is submitted.

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['reset_password']))
        {
            $old_pass=$_POST['txtoldpassword'];
            $new_pass=$_POST['txtnewpass1'];
            $re_pass=$_POST['txtnewpass2'];

            if($row['password']==md5($old_pass)){
                if($new_pass==$re_pass){
                    $changed_password=md5($re_pass);
                    $email = $row['email'];
                    $query = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE user SET password='$changed_password' WHERE email='$email'") or die("Could not change password at this time.");
                    $stmt->execute(":password",$changed_password);

                    ?>

                      <div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible'>
                        <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                            <strong>Password Updated Successfully</strong>
                      </div>

                <?php
                }
                else{
                    ?>

                      <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                        <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                            <strong>Your new passwords do not match</strong>
                      </div>

                <?php
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ?>

                      <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                        <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                            <strong>Your old password is incorrect</strong>
                      </div>

            <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Thanks for any help you can give. Note that I have inspected $email = $row['email']; and it is returning the currently logged in user.

Comment: Please read how to bind values with `execute()` in the documentation. You are doing it the right way here: `$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']))`

Comment: Thanks got it. Not sure how to upvote your answer. I'll put up the corrected code for anyone else.

Comment: I've changed the code above to include the solution provided by Paul Spiegel and micster. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making several mistakes : SQL injection, bad PDO usage

### SQL injection

Don't use variable right in your query. Use binding as you do in your connexion setup :

```
// wrong
$query = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE user SET password='$changed_password' WHERE email='$email'")

// correct
$query = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE user SET password=:password WHERE email=:email")
```

### Bad PDO usage

You are using binding but your query doesn't contain what you are trying to bind

With the SQL injection fix you can try two options :

```
// bind with specific function
$query->bindParam(':password', $changed_password);
$query->bindParam(':email', $email);

// bind in execute() function
$query->execute([
    ':password' => $changed_password,
    ':email'    => $email,
]);
```

Read more about PDO and `execute()` function here : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: Thank you, I changed it around. I got it. Cheers

Comment: I've changed the code above to include the solution provided by Paul Spiegel and micster. Thank you both